# Which tools/libraries do you use to unit test your PL/PgSQL

Tags: unit-testing, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How do you unit test your PL/PgSQL? Which libraries/tools do you use?

What percentage of your code is covered by unit tests and how do you measure it? How do you decide which modules to unit test first?

Do you think the time and effort which you invested in your unit testing harness has paid off or not?

If you do not use unit testing, can you explain why not?

Comment: While the topic is interesting, this question as you have asked it is a poor fit for this site, as it is inviting an extended discussion of multiple points, rather than standalone answers to a specific question or problem. Check out these help articles: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I have a function `public.foo(bar text) returns text`...

I create another function like this:

```
create or replace function test.foo() returns void as $$
begin

  perform assert_equals('stuff', public.foo('thing'));
  perform assert_null(public.foo(null));
  ...

end $$ language plpgsql;
```

I have some assert functions like the following. I purposely use the same names and signatures as JUnit.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assert_equals(expected text, actual text) RETURNS void AS $$
begin
        if expected = actual or (expected is null and actual is null) then
            --do nothing
        else
            raise exception 'Assertion Error. Expected <%> but was <%>', expected, actual;
        end if;

end $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I also have a function to run all tests:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.run_all() RETURNS void AS $$
declare
    skip constant name[] = '{run_all}';
    test_schema_name constant name = 'test';
    proc pg_catalog.pg_proc%rowtype;
    started timestamptz;
begin

    raise notice 'Time(m)   Name';
    for proc in select p.* from pg_catalog.pg_proc p join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n on pronamespace = n.oid where nspname = test_schema_name and not proname = any(skip) order by proname loop
        started = clock_timestamp();
        execute format('select %s.%s();', test_schema_name, proc.proname);
        raise notice '% %.%()', to_char(clock_timestamp() - started, 'MI:SS:MS'), test_schema_name, proc.proname;
    end loop;  

end $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Regarding your questions:

> What percentage of your code is covered by unit tests and how do you
>   measure it?

Not sure. Guess I need a code coverage tool.

UPDATE: looks like you can check code coverage with https://github.com/kputnam/piggly

> How do you decide which modules to unit test first?

The most [complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) ones.

> Do you think the time and effort which you invested in your unit
>   testing harness has paid off or not?

Definitely glad I am using unit testing.

Also look into:

http://pgtap.org/
http://en.dklab.ru/lib/dklab_pgunit/
http://www.epictest.org/